# NodeJS isn't working in Azure Deployed MEAN-stack web-app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, azure, web-applications, mean-stack

Just deployed My MEAN-stack web app in Azure and everything works as it should except for my NodeJS/Express server. My angular is sending Http-requests but none of them are reaching my NodeJS server named `server.js` Nor is this file handling the requests every request that is made returns 404 Not found.
It only works when I run the nodejs locally.

This web-app worked perfectly fined when everything was running locally but now it just can't seem to find my deployed NodeJS.

I Uploaded the entire project into Azure via VS, entire project meaning, my Angular code, html code, ser.js file and web.config, etc. 
I do not know on what port I should be listening in my nodejs. When I was running it locally i used http://localhost:27017 for my angular traffic and used to listen on port 27017 on my nodeJS. But now that it's deployed on Azure I assume I can't use this port anymore?

Comment: How are you deploying the nodejs app to server? ftp, from github, direct deploying via VS, etc?

Comment: Please edit your question with more details such s how you deployed it (is it all in a VM? Part of it in an Azure Web App?), how you opened the port to listen for traffic, etc. As it stands, there's not enough detail to go on.

Comment: @BotanMan I deployed the entire app using VS?

Comment: Hm, are the Angular app and NodeJs server are different apps? I mean does NodeJS server return, for example, 'index.html' that is angular app, or nodeJS is pure restful service?

Comment: @BotanMan I updated my description if it's any help? Do you think I should host my node on a seperate API app ?

Comment: First of all it will be available only in case if NodeJs server works on 80 port (it relates to AzureWebSites default settings), and it shouldn't be requested via localhost, it should be requested via Azure Web Site external url like app.azurewebsites.net

Comment: And Im afraid its not possible to use restful NodeJs server and separate angular app on the same azure web site instance.

Comment: @BotanMan So I will have to deploy my nodeJS on a seperate API app and link to this api in angular?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100304/discussion-between-botanman-and-tom-kustermans).

Answer (score 0):

As Node.js applications running on Azure Web Apps Service, are hosted on IISNode, which gives a `named pipe` to receive the incoming requests, not a TCP port. And on platform tier, Azure Web Apps only expose 80,443 port to public.

You can directly set request url to your Node.js application endpoint in the `angular` code. The following is my code snippets for your information based on the `express web app template`:

```
/public
 |-angluar.html:

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://cdn.bootcss.com/angular.js/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">
          <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
              {{response}}
          </div>
    </body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app
    .controller('testCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('http://<your_web_ap_name>.azurewebsites.net/users').then(function (data) {
            $scope.response = data;
        })
    })
</script>
</html>

/routes
 |-user.js:

exports.list = function(req, res){
  res.send("respond with a resource");
};
```

`server.js`:
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

browse the url: `http://<your_web_app_name>.azurewebsites.net/angular.html`

Comment: It doesn't return any json whatsoever. When I would go to http://<myapp>.azurewebsites.net/Exercise I should get all the exercises in database printed, but sadly i do not. have no idea why this is. My NodeJS simply isn't running or deploying

Comment: First, you can directly browse your endpoint `http://<myapp>.azurewebsites.net/Exercise` to check whether your Node.js server works fine. But per your comment, there is something wrong with your Node.js server. And according your another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34712509/error-when-deploying-nodejs-server-in-web-api-app-azure/34714758?noredirect=1#comment57193708_34714758, which seems currently the mongodb connection issue is the criminal.

Comment: https://codegenieapi.azurewebsites.net/Exercise I have no clue what the issue is, honestly, that's Why I'm asking all these questions :)

Comment: I can get a list of data from the link you provide, like `[{"_id":"56616178e4b048264f08015e","semester":1,"week":1,"Title":"Inleiding","Description":"\r\n1)......`,  so what do you mean "Nodejs isn't working"?

Comment: what?really? how? It's working for me now too ? never touched it? I don't get it... Oh well I'm not complaining ^^

Comment: I just directly opened your link in broswer. And I also tried your link in angular app. You can try with another computer, if it works fine on other computers, you may check the env between your pc and others.

Comment: But it's okay, for some mysterious reason this works for me also now. Don't get it but oh well :)

Comment: Whatever, congratulations.