# Error when deploying nodejs server in web api app Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, mongoose, azure-api-apps

I am trying to deploy this nodeJS server as web API app in azure and I can't seem to get this running, after fixing verious object i keep getting other errors and can't seem to get this api up and running. so please helpe me out. here is the error I am getting: [image]

---

I'm using the debugconsole to check if this node can be deployed and this is where i keep getting error after error but i just can't seem to be able to get this api up and running PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 0):

`getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` means mongodb client was not able to connect to given address.

You can try to check your `mongodb server` locally, E.G.

I create a mongodb server on an ubuntu VM on Azure as [Install MongoDB on a Windows VM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-install-mongodb-windows-server/)
 shows, then leverage the following code snippet, which works fine on my side:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var connectionString = 'mongodb://<server_name>.cloudapp.net:27017/';
MongoClient.connect(connectionString,function(err,db){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.send(200,{message:'Something went wrong when connecting to db'});
    }else{
        db.close();
        res.send(200,{message:'Connected correctly to db'});
    }
})
```

### update

I create a simple test code project on Azure Web Apps try to reproduce the issue, but it works fine on my side, I'd like to point out my env and code snippet for your information:

my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "jade": "*",
    "express": "~3.1.0",
    "mongoose":"*"
  },
```

my code snippets of mongoose with MongoLab connectionString:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   mongoose.connect('mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds058048.mongolab.com:58048/<dbname>');
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function (callback) {
        console.log('db open!');
        res.send(200,{message:'Connected correctly to db'});
    });
};
```

And the connectionstring is shown as [Quick-Start Guide to MongoLab](http://docs.mongolab.com/#connect) mentions.

Comment: I am using mongoose instead of mongoDB is that's any help? But what you are saying is that I'm passing and incorrect ConnectionString to my database?

Comment: It's ok whatever the third part Node.js module. The point is that the ConnectionString to your database. Could you tell me where you host your mongodb on?

Comment: I'm hosting my mongoDB on MongoLab. And could you tell me what the point in with the Connection String ?

Comment: I had a test project on Azure with expressjs and mongoose connecting to MongoLab, but everything worked fine on my side, I provide my dependencies and code snippets as update. any further concern, please feel free to let me know.